# How do I install kodi 16.1 on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, 17.10, kodi

Its kind of as follows...I just want the older version, yet I have not a lick of knowledge on how to do it.

Comment: Just saying in case you don't know: the old skin "Confluence" is [still available](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Change_skins) for Kodi > 17.

Comment: No I know, I'm just more comfortable with 16, for 17 I have found it much less customizable and much less stable.  For instance I was trying to watch King of the Hill this morning on it and I constantly got this flickering white bar.  I also use this custom theme made for xbmc called Metro confluence https://www.deviantart.com/art/Skin-Metro-confluence-XBMC-292627841, which also runs much more stable on 16 than 17 (of course with a couple minor bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned of you have already got the latest version of kodi installed on your system so here are the instructions incase you do.

if you need to uninstall Kodi and remove the stable PPA before installing the 16.1 version.

the following command will remove the latest PPA form your system.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
```

Next to add the PPA for the old version of kodi and install it run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/kodi-old
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove kodi*
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

for more infomation see the kodi wiki here - http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux

Comment: Nope...Still installing Kodi 17.3  It may be on the default software channel.  Would this whole thing work if I disabled the software channel that came with my lubuntu installation?

Comment: Yes it is possible that may be affecting it.

Comment: Also after looking at launchpad, it seems Kodi only goes up to xenial in the packages.  Would that mean I cant download an older version?

Comment: @TomHancock if a precompiled package is unavailable, you can probably grab the source (.udeb) of that xenial package and compile it locally.  this would give you the version of Kodi you want, compiled for your ubuntu version.

Comment: How would I go about compiling and possibly modifying the file to fit the system though?

Comment: Better yet, how would I be able to get the necessary file to do it with

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, 27th October 2017, you cannot install KODI on Ubuntu 17.10 if you are using the Wayland or X org drivers as it keeps coming up with unmet dependencies. It works with the NVidia drivers, but you have to make sure Wayland is disabled.

[From KODI Forum](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=322727)

Edit: 28th October 2017.

Issue seems resolved as I have installed KODI 17.5 through the team-xbmc repo and all is working. I did prefer the older skin, but the newer version seems more compatible with add-ons.